# How to use Gibb's sampling when the conditional probability doesn't depend on the observations

Tags: bayesian, conditional-probability, prior, gibbs

I have a model that looks like this

$$ x(k) = \sum_{m}^{M} e^{i (U_m k + \beta_m)} + n(k)$$

Where $U_m$ has a Gaussian distribution with parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$.

$$ U_m \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)  $$ and $\beta_m$ has a uniform distribution

$$ \beta_m \sim \mathcal{U}(0, 2\pi) $$

The $n$ is an additive zero mean complex Gaussian noise

$$ \Re(n) \sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma_n^2) $$

$$ \Im(n) \sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma_n^2) $$

I want to estimate $\mu$ and $\sigma$ when $M$ is a large number. I wanted to use Gibbs's sampling. However, when I tried to find the conditional probabilities, I found that they are not dependent on the data anymore when $M$ is large and $\sigma_n$ is known.

$$ p(\mu | \sigma, x) = p(\mu | \sigma) $$

and

$$ p(\sigma | \mu, x) = p(\sigma | \mu) $$

It is explained [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/584502/conditional-probabilities-of-the-parameters).

If I think of my application, these prior probabilities may not depend on each other a lot either. So,

$$ p(\mu | \sigma) = p(\mu) $$ and

$$ p(\sigma | \mu) = p(\sigma) $$

What I don't understand is how this will work. I don't have an intuitive prior for both these parameters (Any recommendation is appreciated). I just have intuitive initial points for these two parameters. If there is no dependence on data, how can I estimate these two parameters based on Gibbs's sampling? Should I consider something else in this case?

Comment: The answer to your earlier question is only asymptotic. For a fixed value of $M$, the distribution of the sample $x(1),x(2),\ldots,x(K)$ depends on $\mu$ and $\sigma$. A full Gibbs sampler would incorporate the $U_m$'s and the $\beta_m$ as latent variables.

Comment: @Xi'an the noise is complex. I edited the question. 
I want to understand your comment about the asymptotic behaviour and about the latent variables. What I saw is that for a large M, the distribution of x(1) to x(K) approaches Gaussian but it’s still dependent on mu and sigma. But as the dependence becomes lower when M becomes higher, I framed my question like this. However, I think it should depend on the parameters it’s very difficult to find that distribution. How can I approach the same problem with latent variables? What did you mean by that?

Comment: @Xi'an I am very new to statistical inference problems. So, I couldn't understand fully what you said. Could you please elaborate it if possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $\sigma_n$ is a known parameter, the question is about simulating from the posterior distribution of $(\mu,\sigma^2)$ given a sample of $x(k)'s$ (e.g., $x(1),\ldots,x(K)$)
$$p(\mu,\sigma|x(1),\ldots,x(K))\propto p(\mu,\sigma)\times f(x(1),\ldots,x(K)|\mu,\sigma)$$
As expressed in the question, this joint distribution density $$f(x(1),\ldots,x(K)|\mu,\sigma)$$is not easily computed and hence an MCMC algorithm is difficult to implement, incl. the specific case of the Gibbs sampler.

One traditional approach in simulation (and found in one of the earliest Gibbs samplers, see Tanner & Wong, 1987) is to complement the vector to be simulated, $(\mu,\sigma)$, with latent or auxiliary variables in order to achieve a manageable joint density. We call this method *demarginalisation* in [our book](http://amzn.to/2lQDmJR) and it simply means that simulating from the marginal density $p(\cdot)$ can proceed by (i) constructing a manageable but otherwise arbitrary joint density $q(\cdot,\cdot)$ such that $p$ is its marginal:
$$p(u)=\int q(u,v)\,\text dv$$
and (ii) simulate from this joint $q$ a sample of $(u_i,v_i)_{i=1,\ldots,I}$'s, because the $u_i$'s will then be distributed from $p$.

In the current setting, the latent variables are naturally available as made of the $\mathbf U=U_1,\ldots,U_M$ and $\mathfrak B=\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_M$ since the original model can be decompose as the hierarchy of distributions
\begin{align}
x(k)|\mathbf U,\mathfrak B &\sim \mathcal N\left(\sum_{m}^{M} \exp\{i (U_m k + \beta_m)\},\sigma_n^2\right)\\
U_m|\mu,\sigma &\sim \mathcal N\left(\mu,\sigma^2\right)\\
\beta_m &\sim \mathcal U(0,2\pi)\\
\mu,\sigma &\sim p(\mu,\sigma)
\end{align}
and the associated demarginalisation is
$$p(\mu,\sigma|x(1),\ldots,x(K)) = \int p(\mu,\sigma,\mathbf U,\mathfrak B|x(1),\ldots,x(K))\,\text d(\mathbf U,\mathfrak B)$$
Furthermore, thanks to the hierarchical decomposition
$$p(\mu,\sigma,\mathbf U,\mathfrak B|x(1),\ldots,x(K))\propto
p(\mu,\sigma)\times\prod_m \mathfrak u(\beta_m)\times\prod_m \varphi(U_m|\mu,\sigma)\times\prod_{k=1}^K\varphi(x(k)|\mathbf U,\mathfrak B)$$
the joint distribution can be easily simulated by a Gibbs sampler based on the full conditional. Obviously, if $M$ and/or $K$ is large, this sampler may be time consuming and slowly mixing.